# Writing on the backs of CDs and DVDs: Dangerous?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, disc

Maybe it's completely a superstition, but I was told when I was younger to *never* **ever** write on the back of burnable media. Does this have any basis in fact? I was told that it weakened the discs which would cause them to break.

Comment: Well, you have the data there. When you write on them, you use a paint/ink/whatsoever, which got different components.

Comment: Well, I definitely wouldn't write on the actual data side, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Just a guess. Some devices heat up the disk quite a bit when reading it full-time. I even had a disk explode once. (Probably a bad device though). So you may want to make sure the ink handle the heat correctly. (maybe some bad inks burn at low enough temperatures ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can damage data by writing on CDs in one of two ways:

1. Scratching - as @francis mentioned, if you use a hard-tip pen or pencil you may scratch the material and create enough damage that the reading laser won't be able to "see" certain sectors
2. Ink seepage - if you use a fountain pen, or a type of marker that leaves a great deal of ink behind, it might seep to the other side, and again destroy readable areas.

My suggestion is: just use a sharpie, or pens dedicated to writing on burnable media. And don't press too hard :)

Answer (score 1):

Well yeah if you carve a inscription into them with a **ballpoint pen**, it might have issues.  Soft tips like sharpies should be fine however.

Answer (score 1):

none whatsoever. writing on cds with felt tip, permanant markers is an accepted way of labelling them. Just don't use a ballpoint, but this is cause it'd damage the data layer.

Chances of a cd breaking in a cd drive takes are slim since it takes a [fair bit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOb6Z5Tja68)

Answer (score 1):

Needless to say, also make sure the writing is completely dry before putting in the drive or stacking another disc on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sharpie or similar is fine. However, if you use a pencil, ballpoint pen, or other hard-tipped pen, you won't be able to write on it AND you risk losing data.